# Unable to access attribute of an object

Tags: reactjs

I have these objects, which I appended to them an image URL, however, when I try to call that URL just so I can verify that it worked, it doesn't show up. Every other attribute, be it an 'id', a 'name' gets printed out but the URL doesn't.

When I type in the following code:
`{trendingMovies.map((movie)=><img src={movie.img} />)}` 
I get the following result:
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVzvn.png)

But after I try to print out some other attribute
`{trendingMovies.map((movie)=><p>{movie.original_title}</p>)}`

I get the needed result [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCLgA.png)

Lastly, I'll append another image so you see what I'm working with
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLS3w.png)

I'm really baffled as to I've never experienced anything like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the function I use to append it:

```
const getPoster=(movie)=>{
    const poster = axios(`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie}`);
   return  poster.then(function(data){
         return data.config.url;
     })
    }
const appendToObj=(url, obj)=>{
    url.then(data =>obj.img = data);
}
```

Afterwards I loop through the array of objects and for each object I call both methods, the first which takes the URL and the second which appends it

Comment: please correct it.====> {trendingMovies.map((movie)=><img src={movie.img} />)} ... you are using paragraph tag instead of img tag.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar it should still work as raw text but that's worth a try. I wonder if there's any asynchronous updating going on here?

Comment: Tried doing it, still get the empty `<img>` tags

Comment: @TonislavTachev , are you getting image in every object of array ... checked in console?

Comment: @Vahid Akhtar, yes I am getting the img property to append to each object of my array

Comment: @TonislavTachev can you share that api or api response data please so i could check.

Comment: Can OP share a [mcve] to reproduce the problem and avoid all the guesswork on behalf of answerers?

Comment: How are you calling `appendToObj` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
     const trendingMovies = [
       { 'id': 1, 'img': 'url1', dedia_type: 'movie' },
       { 'id': 2, 'img': 'url2', dedia_type: 'movie' }
     ]      
      trendingMovies.map((m) => (`<p>${m.img}</p>`))
```